Access denied for Remote Thread Creation with windows API
I am trying to crash my notepad processs. I wrote the following code:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("mssing argument \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    HANDLE hProcess, hThread = NULL;

    BOOL bWrite;
    LPVOID lValloc;

    LPCVOID lpBuffer = "\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41";
    DWORD PID = atoi(argv[1]), TID = atoi(argv[1]);

    printf("pid is %ld\n", PID);
    
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);

    if (hProcess == NULL) {
        printf("Impossible to access process, error code :%ld\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    lValloc = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(lpBuffer), (MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if (lValloc == NULL) {
        printf("Impossible to allocate memory, error code :  %ld", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    bWrite = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lValloc, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), NULL);

    if(bWrite == 0){
        printf("Impossible to write in memory, error code : %ld\n", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lValloc, NULL, 0, &TID);

    if(hThread == NULL) {
        printf("CreateRemoteThread failed, error code: %ld\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

When I execute the code with the pid I have the following error:
C:\Users\vbrain\source\repos\malware>a.exe 19236
pid is 19236
 CreateRemoteThread failed, error code: 5

I actually checked what this 5 error is related to. It appears to be ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
However I put correct access: PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
What am I missing ?

Not related to the error, but: 1) sizeof(lpBuffer) does not report what you think it does. Change LPCVOID lpBuffer to BYTE lpBuffer[5] instead; 2) do not use PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, specify only the specific rights you actually need, which in this case is PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ; 3) if CreateRemoteThread() were successful, you need to wait on the thread to finish and then cleanup the memory you allocated.
